# How replace theme styles?

Tags: customization, themes, css

I have some theme. I am running shortcode for my plugin in some page like this:

`[my_plugin_code atr="1"]`

But all styles is import from CSS theme. I want my custom CSS. How to do it without interfering with template styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress dashboard
-> Appeareance menu
  -> Customizer

allows you to add custom CSS without editing any files.

Comment: Note that those CSS customizations only apply to the current theme. If you change themes, then additional customizations would possibly be needed.  It also depends on what your shortcode does. But, the answer from @jdewitt is basically correct.

Comment: I know customizer but no matter i write in style theme, then there is no change. This is big file, probably reset all styles and new declare. I want connect an own styles, preferably from the level of my plugin, but this is probably impossible?

Comment: i have solution. I must use "wp_enqueue_scripts" not "admin_enqueue_scripts"